# Nested Active Directory Groups in a Group

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group, ssis-2008

I have a need to find all the nested groups in a particular group 1 layer down.  The problem I have is the code below usually works, but for some groups it does not.

If I use Windows Explorer to search for a particular group (click on the Network icon, then click on 'Search Active Directory', I can see the members and nested groups within the parent group.  But through code using   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement on 3.5 Framework, `var Groups = MyGroup.GetGroups();` can't see the nested groups of some groups.  I thought it was a permissions thing, but if i can see inside the group from my own manual  search mentioned above, then I assume the code running from the same account should be able to see the same thing too.  Is there something different I should try?

For what its worth, I'm using a script task on top of Framework 3.5 inside of a SSIS package. Also in the same package, searching for groups from a user principle object instead of a group principle works fine.

And for clarity, when I run this code

```
     PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ctx", "mypath");
     GroupPrincipal myGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(AD, "myparentgroup");
     var nestedgroups = myGroup.GetGroups();
```

"Nestedgroups" is null when it should contain my nested groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I had was I used `var Groups = MyGroup.GetGroups();` when I should have used `var Groups = MyGroup.GetMembers();`.  Putting that behind a link statement allowed me to get all the objects I was looking for because  `.GetMembers()` includes users and groups.  Hope that helps.